# Angular 2: Implement a custom context menu

Tags: angular

I'm implementing an Angular 2 attribute directive to allow me to add a custom context menu to an element like this:

```
<p context-menu="myItems">Hello world</p>
```

That directive adds a mouse event handler to catch a right-click, and the idea is to then construct a context menu, add it to the DOM, and then destroy it when the user finishes with it.

I have a component that implements the context menu itself. I'd like to construct that component, call a method on it to set the item list, and then add it to the DOM.

It looks like I might be able to do this with AppViewManager.createHostViewInContainer. Is this an appropriate way to do this? And if so, is there a way to construct/get an ElementRef to `document.body` so that I can tell createHostViewInContainer to construct the component there? Obviously I don't want my menu to be clipped inside the element I'm adding the context menu to.

Comment: Does it really matter where you insert the component? You can just position it absolute. I would add a context menu component to the `AppComponent` and send instructions about what it should display using a shared global service. Hete is an example where HTML is added dynamically to the `body` but not components AFAIK https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2_material/src/components/dialog/dialog.ts

Comment: It matters if the parent has `overflow:hidden`, which many do.

Comment: I've actually wound up using `position:fixed`, which seems to ignore its parent's `overflow:hidden`. It feels a little dirty, but it does get the job done.

Answer (score 27):

Here is what I think is a good way to do it.
You need 1 service, 1 component and 1 directive.

[Here is a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3klGukkbDBCOaBYqcGmr?p=preview)

Explanation:

> The service `ContextMenuService`:

- provides a subject of type `{event:MouseEvent,obj:any[]}` to be
  subscribed to by `ContextMenuHolderComponent`, and to receive values
  from `ContextMenuDirective`

Code:

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class ContextMenuService{

    public show:Subject<{event:MouseEvent,obj:any[]}> = new Subject<{event:MouseEvent,obj:any[]}>();
}
```

And add it to the list of providers in `bootstrap()`

```
bootstrap(AppComponent,[ContextMenuService]);
```

> The Component `ContextMenuHolderComponent`:

- This component is added inside the root component. e.g. `AppComponent` and it has a `fixed` position.
- It subscribes to the `subject` in `ContextMenuService` to receive:

  1. menu items of type `{title:string,subject:Subject}[]`, the subject is used to send the clicked on value inside the menu
  2. MouseEvent object
- It has a `(document:click)` event listener to close the menu on clicks outside the menu.

code:

```
@Component({
  selector:'context-menu-holder',
  styles:[
    '.container{width:150px;background-color:#eee}',
    '.link{}','.link:hover{background-color:#abc}',
    'ul{margin:0px;padding:0px;list-style-type: none}'
  ],
  host:{
    '(document:click)':'clickedOutside()'
  },
  template:
  `<div [ngStyle]="locationCss" class="container">
      <ul>
          <li (click)="link.subject.next(link.title)" class="link" *ngFor="#link of links">
              {{link.title}}
          </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  `
})
class ContextMenuHolderComponent{
  links = [];
  isShown = false;
  private mouseLocation :{left:number,top:number} = {left:0;top:0};
  constructor(private _contextMenuService:ContextMenuService){
    _contextMenuService.show.subscribe(e => this.showMenu(e.event,e.obj));
  }
  // the css for the container div
  get locationCss(){
    return {
      'position':'fixed',
      'display':this.isShown ? 'block':'none',
      left:this.mouseLocation.left + 'px',
      top:this.mouseLocation.top + 'px',
    };
  }
  clickedOutside(){
    this.isShown= false; // hide the menu
  }

  // show the menu and set the location of the mouse
  showMenu(event,links){
    this.isShown = true;
    this.links = links;
    this.mouseLocation = {
      left:event.clientX,
      top:event.clientY
    }
  }
}
```

And add it to the root component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    directives:[ContextMenuHolderComponent,ChildComponent],
    template: `
    <context-menu-holder></context-menu-holder>
    <div>Whatever contents</div>
    <child-component></child-component>
    `
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

> The last one, `ContextMenuDirective`:

- It adds a `contextmenu` event to the host element.
- Accept an input of a list of items to be passed to `ContextMenuHolderComponent`.

Code:

```
@Directive({
  selector:'[context-menu]',
  host:{'(contextmenu)':'rightClicked($event)'}
})
class ContextMenuDirective{
  @Input('context-menu') links;
  constructor(private _contextMenuService:ContextMenuService){
  }
  rightClicked(event:MouseEvent){
    this._contextMenuService.show.next({event:event,obj:this.links});
    event.preventDefault(); // to prevent the browser contextmenu
  }
}
```

That's it. All you need to do now is attach the `[context-menu]` directive to an element and bind it to a list of items. For example:

```
@Component({
  selector:'child-component',
  directives:[ContextMenuDirective],
  template:`
  <div [context-menu]="links" >right click here ... {{firstRightClick}}</div>
  <div [context-menu]="anotherLinks">Also right click here...{{secondRightClick}}</div>
  `
})
class ChildComponent{
  firstRightClick; secondRightClick;
  links;
  anotherLinks;
  constructor(){
    this.links = [
      {title:'a',subject:new Subject()},
      {title:'b',subject:new Subject()},
      {title:'b',subject:new Subject()}
    ];
    this.anotherLinks = [
      {title:'link 1',subject:new Subject()},
      {title:'link 2',subject:new Subject()},
      {title:'link 3',subject:new Subject()}
    ];
  }

  // subscribe to subjects
  ngOnInit(){
    this.links.forEach(l => l.subject.subscribe(val=> this.firstCallback(val)));
    this.anotherLinks.forEach(l => l.subject.subscribe(val=> this.secondCallback(val)))
  }
  firstCallback(val){
    this.firstRightClick = val;
  }
  secondCallback(val){
    this.secondRightClick = val;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what `=` does in here `public show:Subject<{event:MouseEvent,obj:any[]}> = new Subject();`. I cannot find information about this notation. `tsc` complains about `Type 'Subject<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Subject...`

Comment: @Zhytkevich This is just assigning a new subject to `show`. The complaint is because I haven't specified the subject `type`. You can get rid of it by doing `public show:Subject<{event:MouseEvent,obj:any[]}> = new Subject<{event:MouseEvent,obj:any[]}>();`. Or simply by making the subject of type `any` like `public show:Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();`

Comment: hi @Abdulrahman, I tried the app but I am stuck at context-menu.service.ts on Injectable annotation, this compilation error is comming **Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression.
  Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.**

Comment: @rish it seems like you are passing parameters into the `@Injectable()` decorator. While `@Injectable()` doesn't accept any parameters.

Comment: @Abdulrahman thnx for response, I tried but when I am executing in console there are no error showing but in browser nothing is displaying.

Comment: @rish Could you put your code in a plunker ? It's hard to tell where the problem is without the code.

Comment: @Abdulrahman hi I have created plunker. please check https://plnkr.co/edit/6XoGpvoEqMZ21syYKy12?p=preview

Comment: @rish, it's working fine, you just needed to set up angular, here is [your plunker edited](http://plnkr.co/edit/WDzmeIDKwCXQpJctKVv3?p=preview).

Comment: hi @Abdulrahman, I have one question, how I can show another context menu inside one. Like if user click on link1 then another context menu open with list of link. thank you in andvance