# Angular6 Default ContextMenu

Tags: html, angular, angular6

I am working on a project in Angular 6, where I have used `(click)="actionNavigateAway()"` to direct page to a new Url. This works perfectly fine on the <kbd>left click</kbd>. But on the <kbd>right click</kbd>, it shows up a context menu having options like `Back`, `Reload`, etc (as shown in the 1st photo).

[image]

Instead, what I want to show is the default context menu that we usually find on right clicking a link (figure 2). I have searched the web and found ways to make a custom contextmenu, but nothing for the default. Can you please help me with that? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Can you share your code in stackblitz ?

Comment: People are posting comment as a answer just for 50 rep, rep race is never gonna end here :D

Comment: @javan.rajpopat Those are different context menus because the source of the context menus are different elements, in second image it says open a **link** in new tab, because it's a link, you cannot open div into a new tab can you? and for customizing default context menu, for some security reasons browsers does not allow you to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/textlevel-semantics.html#the-a-element)

> If the a element has an href attribute, then it represents a hyperlink
>   (a hypertext anchor) labeled by its contents.
>
> If the a element has no href attribute, then the element represents a
>   placeholder for where a link might otherwise have been placed, if it
>   had been relevant, consisting of just the element’s contents.

So it's not considered as a hyperlink.
Just add an empty href attribute. Like this,

```html
  <a (click)="actionNavigateAway()">Not Working</a>
 <br/>
 <a href="" (click)="actionNavigateAway()">Working</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use JS to route your link, but want the href context menu -you can use both. You can add a blank href or any href, and then pass the event to  prevent default on a function. like so

```
<a href="/somepath" onclick="function(event){event.preventDefault()}">This link has both</a>
```

Now the page won't try to route you to "/somepath" when you click that href link. You can either add more code to the function, or use a JS SPA router to handle the routing. You now have javascript handling your links, and a normal context menu. Since the context menu has an actual route -it will actually open if and only if you select to open in new tab. not an actual click

Answer (score 0):

The default context menu is normally working on link, it's normal that nobody tried to reproduce it ^^

In your case, the only possible problem is that **you're not aiming correctly the link**

But you can also create a custom contextmenu like this : [Angular 2: Implement a custom context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34861628/angular-2-implement-a-custom-context-menu)

Answer (score 0):

The context menu should work when right clicking a link with a `href` attribute.

```html
<a>This is a A tag without attributes</a><br>
<a href="#">This A tag has a href attribute</a><br>
<a onclick="hi()">This A tag has a onclick attribute</a><br>
```

So that means that you should use the `href` attribute instead of a click handler.

Try and run the snippet and right click on the different 'links' to see what I mean.